# How do I move the Long Gui?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I'm on the Archylte Steppe in ???AF, and I'm supposed to defeat some dragon-like monster that's causing storms, but it's being blocked by a Long Gui. Noel suggested going back to the village to ask how to move it, but no one seems to want to talk except the lady that's offering to explain the weather device again. How am I supposed to do this? I tried fighting it, but that went very, very poorly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you set the weather to make the Long Gui and Faeryl appear (Sunny no wind).
Next move the dial on the right once (this will cause lightning but no wind): Long Gui will be gone but Faeryl will stay.

Answer (score -1):

If your at a high level like max crystal lvl 99, everything you can, beat it or change weather to stormy to make it go away.